optional vector of enum initializer list
In the following case, when using assignment on an optional vector of enum values I cannot explain the behavior of the code. Why does assignment of ... = {C} compile and create a vector of size 2, while ... = {2} does not compile?
enum Type
{
    A, B, C
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::optional<std::vector<Type>> types;

    types = { A };
    std::cout << types->size() << std::endl; // => 0

    types = { C };
    std::cout << types->size() << std::endl; // => 2

    // Conclusion, this uses the vector size constructor as the enum can be converted to integer (sicne it is not defined as enum class).
    // So i should be able to just provde the size as an integer instead of a `Type`? but:
    // types = { 7 };
    // does not compile. -> EDIT it does, intellisense is wrong
    // Then what is allowing the previous lines to use the vector size constructor?
}

And this works as expected, which gives the behavior I expected for the first example aswell.
enum class TypeClass
{
    A, B, C
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::optional<std::vector<TypeClass>> types;
    types = { TypeClass::A };
    types = { TypeClass::C };
}


Because A == 0 and C == 2. Your assignment creates a vector of those sizes.

@Someprogrammerdude yes thats the conclusion I wrote down, but then why does types = { 2 } not compile?

Hmm... both types = { A }; and types = { C }; constructs / assigns a std::vector<Type> containing one element. What compiler makes the program show the sizes 0 and 2 ?

@TedLyngmo This is on msvc2019

@Aedoro I'd say MSVC2019 is buggy in that case. It should print 1 and 1 and the reason 7 doesn't work is that's 7 is not a Type. You could force it though: types = { Type(7) };. Can you upgrade to MSVC2022? It should hopefully be better.

@TedLyngmo Ok my bad, it does compile, intellisense predicts that it doesn't with "no viable operator matches ...". (It definitely still prints 0 and 2 though)

https://godbolt.org/z/1voWrqa9K on MSVC if fails in both cases.

Regarding your comment in the code: "does not compile. -> EDIT it does, intellisense is wrong" - This is one of the rare cases where IntelliSense is right and the compiler is wrong.

This is not a [mcve]

@Aedoro I just tried it out in MSVC2022 and it does the right thing (prints 1 and 1 and refuses to compile types = { 7 }) - so my advice is to upgrade.

Should the size constructor no be explicit? AFIAK the initializer list constructor should always be preferred over the others. I hope the future std, removes the tag from_range and makes range constructors cannon. In presence of views::repeat, sized constructor should become deprecated.

This seems to be another msvc bug which is fixed in the latest version. Latest version of msvc start accepting the program just like gcc and clang does. Demo

That's a long-time-running bug in Microsoft compiler related to coversions in intializer (another symptom - failing to compile if a unified  initializer contains float instead of double  or int instead of int64) e.g. int sz = 42; std::vector v  = {sz}; fails, And it STILL not fully fixed in recent versions. Most of the time such code can be avoided. It almost looks like it gets flagged as "it matches our code standard - won't fix it", which was known to be a thing in past.
